# Querying fields containing multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I need to query a table from a MariaDB source.

There is a field that contains several values separated by a comma, and I don't know how to go on.

That's the situation:

```
TABLE: Aphorisms_Categories
Field: id
```

related with

```
TABLE: Aphorisms
Field: categories
```

The problem is that categories often contains a strings like 2, 3, 4, 67.

The original developer, I don't know why, decided not to create a third table to represent N-M relations. But now, for me, it's impossible to figure out a way to retrieve all aphorisms belonging to category 3 (for example).

Any hint?

Comment: is it still an option to add that extra table and store the values there? Maybe use triggers to insert/update those values in the extra table, while keeping your php code in tact mostly

Comment: _There's a field that contains several values separated by a comma_ Sounds like a bad design or just the wrong database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shirkam's answer is close but there is one problem:

If 3 is the first or last category in the field, i.e '2,4,33,3', than 
`SELECT * FROM Aphorisms WHERE categories LIKE '%,3,%'`
won't catch it. And if you remove the commas from the LIKE clause then you'll get false positives on multi digit categories.

Since you're using MariaDB use:
`SELECT * FROM Aphorisms WHERE categories REGEXP '(^|,)3($|,)'`

Answer (score 0):

You sould use something like this:

`SELECT * FROM Aphorisms WHERE categories LIKE '%,3,%`

This will do the trick.

PS: Sometimes, developers don't want to have too many relations, so the tend to concentrate things. Sometimes its useful, sometimes not, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The only one good solution can only be the one imposed by your responsibility as a good programmer: to provide not only a good php code, but also a good database design. You have now this responsibility, not anymore the former developer.

So, my recommendation would be not to try to apply find-category-id tricks, but to provide a good, solid database design. Like you already proposed in your question.

Good luck!

Comment: For the users who downvote(d) my question: Please let me know the motive(s) of your downvotes, so that I can change my answer correspondingly. This way we can contribute together to the continuous improvement of this website.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do what you suggest. The database is the one I have, and I cannot change it.